# comparing key of one hash with value of another to create third hash in perl

Tags: perl, hash

I want to merge identical values of hash1 and hash2 and create a third hash with key of hash3 is key of hash1 and value of hash3 is key of hash2 for those identical values

```
%hash3 = (
    0 =>3,
    1 => 2,
    2 => 1,
    3 => 0
);
```

Comment: Why is the `0` key in `%hash3` 3?

Comment: What it is you want to do? It's not clear to me

Comment: You should first formulate your task in plain words. Then just convert it to code. Right now I have no idea how did you get from your data to the result.

Comment: I think because `0` in `%hash1` and `3` in `%hash2` contain the same value.

Answer (score 1):

[`reverse`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/reverse.html) `%hash2` and then use [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) to pair keys from `%hash1` with what used to be the keys of `%hash2`:

```
my %reversed = reverse %hash2;
my %hash3 = map { $_ => $reversed{$hash1{$_}} } keys %hash1;
```

`%hash3` contains:

```
{
    '1' => '2',
    '0' => '3',
    '3' => '0',
    '2' => '1'
};
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time ! Works great :)

Comment: @marie it should be noted that if values in original %hash2 are repeated and you reverse your hash then you will loose data as keys in hash have to be unique. Hope you are aware of it.